# Insert value to 2d array

Tags: java

I have a loop to loop through 0-200 and if the number matches the number in the list. I will put it inside the freq[][]. However, I'm having problem into putting the numbers I found into the freq[][] considering that it needs to be  in the size of [10][20].

```
public static void example(List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> elements, int[][] list){

        int index = 0;
        int[][] freq = new int[10][20];
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
            for (int x = 0; x < list.length; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < list[x].length; y++){
                    if (list[x][y] == i){
                        freq[][index] = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're incrementing the `index` variable and you have you pass in some sort of counter variable as an index into `int [][] freq` like such `freq[counter_variable][another_counter_variable`. I suggest trying to compile/run the code you posted as it'll provided you a stepping stone for resolving any syntax errors..

Comment: @ces_1094 yes im thinking of having the counter variable but I dont know how to move to the next row if the column size is reached.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as I believe some important information is omitted.  If this is a homework assignment then please include the exact words of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it as

```
if (list[x][y]== i){
 freq[x][y] = i;
} 
 else {
freq[x][y] = 0;  // if not matched
}
```

So that freq will be a two dimensional array with 10rows and 20 columns .

-Element at 5th index position in the list will be in 0*5th position in the 10*20 array.
-Element at 199 th index position in the list will be in 9*19th position in the 10*20 array.

Answer (score 0):

first, you make a loop to read 200 numbers inside this loop you want to loop 2d array to compare its elements by every number and make condition if a number exist in list but it in freq[][]  this code put every number Achieves the condition in freq array and otherwise but 0

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < list[j].length; k++) {
            if(list[j][k]==i)
                freq[j][k]=i;

        }

    }

}
```

if you use     `

```
else 
freq[j][k]=0;
```

`

that mean it start putting  in array the number or 0, and finally, you get an array don't match you want,  so let if condition only without else I test it and it work for me